# How can I convert a .jpg or .png image to .raw format?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing, image-editor

Is there any software that converts JPEG or PNG to RAW?

I have been looking around and I've only found applications that do the reverse.

Comment: why do you want to convert jpg to raw? It's pointless. Converting png to raw might also produces unexpected results, because png files are already demosaicized (if taken from camera), unlike filter camera sensors

Comment: @phuclv Because some programs only accept raw files as input (like Unity reading heightmaps).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just find out [here](http://newton64.github.io/blog/2013-07-24-gimp-unity-terrain.html) how to do that with Gimp !

Works almoust perfectly ! :P

#### Update

Used method:

1. Export the file on Gimp: <kbd>Ctrl Shift E</kbd>
2. On the export window, choose `Raw Image Data` on Select File Type

   1. Click on `Export` button
3. On the raw image export window, Choose `Planar` for the RGB Save Type

   1. Click on `Export` button
4. Open the folder where the file was saved and rename his extension from `.data` to `.raw`
5. On Unity3d, chose `Bit 8` for Depth on the Import Heightmap window

Unfortunately, the generated image by Gimp isn't that good... So, I'm still would appreciate some help.

Comment: If you add the procedure to the answer I will up vote. Please remember to quote but also to place the answer locally for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu by default has Imagemagick installed and provides the `convert` command line tool to convert to various image formats. You can simply do:

```
convert xyx.jpg xyz.RAW
```

Comment: I've just tried this, but got `convert-im6.q16: no encode delegate for this image format 'RAW' @ warning/constitute.c/WriteImage/1180.`

Answer (score 0):

Answer above may work for old versions of ImageMagick, but this worked for me:

```
convert lena512.bmp gray:lena512.raw
```

and vice versa

```
convert -size 512x512 -depth 8 gray:lena512.raw lena512.png
```

For many images this works (I haven't found solution for mogrify):

```
parallel -j 4 convert {} gray:{}.raw ::: slice-*.png
```

`-j` is number of processes, `{}` gets replaced by the filename matching the mask specified after `:::` so output files are named as `slice-0000.png.raw`