# How to bulk convert NEF/RAW images to JPG and remove original images?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, image-processing, imagemagick

I want to convert all NEF/RAW image files to an image format that could be easily opened without additional tools.

I thought about using ImageMagick's `convert` tool as mentioned in [How can I convert a .jpg or .png image to .raw format?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724070/how-can-i-convert-a-jpg-or-png-image-to-raw-format)

However, I don't see any parameter for recursively looking for images in all subfolders nor for removal of old/original images in the [documentation](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) of the `convert` tool.

Should I look for another tool, or the only option is to write some loop around `convert`?

Comment: `find` allows you to recursively find files and folders, and offers the opportunity to execute a command on the files that were found using the `-exec` option. See `man find` to learn about the `find` command. You will also be able to find many examples on how to use `find` and its `-exec` and `-execdir` options.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Imagemagick cannot convert raw image files in recent Ubuntu versions because the `ufraw-batch` package is not available, due to it not being maintained anymore. We can however use [`darktable`](https://www.darktable.org) to do the conversion. To install `darktable` run:

```
sudo apt install darktable
```

You can then use this command that uses [`darktable-cli`](https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/en/special-topics/program-invocation/darktable-cli/) to convert the images:

```bash
find . -type f \( -iname "*.raw" -o -iname "*.nef" \) -exec sh -c 'darktable-cli {} ${0%.*}.jpg' {} \; -delete
```

The above command uses [`find`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/find.1.html) to do the following:

- recursively search in the current folder: `.`
- for files only: `-type f`
- that their name ends either in `.raw` or `.nef`, irrespective of their case: `\( -iname "*.raw" -o -iname "*.nef" \)`
- executes (`-exec`) this command to convert the found files to jpg: `sh -c 'darktable-cli {} ${0%.*}.jpg' {} \;`
- deletes the original files: `-delete`

**Caution:** Make sure to first test the command in a copied portion of your files to ensure that it works as intended!

Comment: This is a great approach. One thing though: doesn't it apply the "darktable defaults"? (which tend to be very neutral)

Comment: @Daniel what do you mean "darktable defaults"?

Comment: I mean that, since RAW images don't contain information about how an image should "look like", darktable applies a default (quite plain) style. They generally look a bit pale and colorless, which aligns with Darktable's motto of leaving all visual choices to the user. I recommend installing/setting up a style (e.g. https://dtstyle.net/) and using the `--style <style-name>` option

Comment: As @Daniel wrote, jpeg should look a bit pale and colorless… I use `exiv2 -ep ` to extract preview pictures included in .NEF (took with Nikon Z50) as described in this post : https://discuss.pixls.us/t/rt-extracting-embedded-jpeg-from-raw-image-using-rt/28067/3

Comment: I had some images with `RAF` file extension. I've replaced `.raw` with `.raf` and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To just be able to view the files, you don't need to develop your raw image with `darktable` or `ufraw`, all common formats have an embedded preview image.

You can extract the preview with e.g. `dcraw`:

```bash
dcraw -e *.CR2
```

Or you can use a proper image viewer that will open the files and show the embdedded preview (e.g. `geeqie`).